# Return data from DialogFragment to calling activity

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have a `DialogFragment` that is working and need to return the selected item from a spinner.  I've tried many methods that I've found on Stack Overflow and other places but they are all using java which doesn't (apparently) translate well to c# in Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017.  To date, nothing has worked  My `DialogFragment` layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:minWidth="300dp" 
    android:minHeight="75dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Select the department you are registering for."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/department_spinner" />
    <Button
        android:text="Ok"
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="34.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/button_ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The class code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace MyProject
{
    class selectDepartment : DialogFragment
    {
        static Spinner department;
        public string selection = "";

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.selectDepartment, container, false);

            Button ok = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_ok);
            department = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.department_spinner);

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("Select Department");
            list.Add("Dept. A");
            list.Add("Dept. B");

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, list.ToArray());
            department.Adapter = adapter;

            ok.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                selection = string.Format("{0}", department.GetItemAtPosition(department.SelectedItemPosition));
            };
            return view;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code that shows the dialog:

```
            FragmentTransaction getdepartment = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            selectDepartment getDept = new selectDepartment();
            getDept.Show(getdepartment , "Select Department");

            // Here I attempt to read a property which contains the selection
            string selection = getDept.selection;
```

In my last attempt, I assigned the spinner selection to a property and I attempt to read that property to get the value selected, but the dialog is (apparently) displayed on a different thread and the selection isn't chosen when that line of code is executed. I tried making my method `async` and `await` the dialog, but that just made matters worse.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a [custom event](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5900/returning-a-value-from-a-dialogfragment)

```
public class DialogEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Selection { get; set; }
}
```

and then in `selectDepartment` add:

```
public delegate void DialogEventHandler(object sender, DialogEventArgs args);

public event DialogEventHandler Dismissed;
```

Finally in the button's click handler add:

```
if (null != Dismissed)
    Dismissed(this, new DialogEventArgs { Selection = selection });
```

when you create the dialog, attach an event handler

```
selectDepartment getDept = new selectDepartment();
getDept.Dismissed += (s, e) => { /* do something with e.Selection here */ };
```

Comment: Just had to make a slight correction to the class `DialogEventArgs`, the `public delegate void DialogEventHandler(object sender, DialogEventArgs args);` was outside the class definition.  Otherwise it worked as expected.  Make that change in your answer and I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks.